# Facebook SDK for Unity3D (Android) - help needed

Tags: facebook, sdk, unity-game-engine

I am running the defualt scene that comes with the facebook SDK

When the FB.Init() is called i get this error

jni: unable to find method for init

There's some info displayed

APPID : id is correctly displayed here

Facebook Dll: Not Loaded

UserID: ""

IsLoggedIn: False

AcessToken: ""

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running unity 4.2 and higher.